# Renaming files from prefix and sufix

Tags: rename

I've a series of media files I'm trying to rename en mass.

```
001 - 01x01 - mediaTitle1.avi
002 - 01x02 - mediaTitle2.avi
003 - 01x03 - mediaTitle3.avi
```

What I'd like is to output:

```
Series Title S01 E01 - mediaTitle1.avi
Series Title S01 E02 - mediaTitle2.avi
Series Title S01 E03 - mediaTitle3.avi
```

I'm trying this:

```
for f in *01x*; do echo mv -v "$f" "Series Title S01 E{f#1}"; done
```

But it's failing.
So I want to keep the end of the file and replace the beginning for each file

Comment: You can use the `rename` command. Filenames have spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but forgot(?) to put `$` at variable expansion, try:

```
for f in  *01x*; do mv -v -- "$f" 'Series Title S01 E'"${f#*01x}"; done
```

Notice single quotes in target file due to spaces in filename.

Comment: Holy moly... It worked.. but I had to remove:
"-v --" Not sure why...

Comment: @Beertastic `-v` is just verbose flag, and `--` informs `mv` that it is the end of options and all next arguments will be filenames. This allow to pass files with `-` in their names, e.g. `-abc.txt`. It really should work with both those flags.

Comment: @jimmij Neither `-v` nor `--` are specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mv.html), so it's possible Beertastic is on a platform that doesn't support them (e.g. [Busybox](http://www.busybox.net/BusyBox.html#mv), [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/mv-1.html)).

Comment: Isn't `--` part of a general POSIX specification for all commands that do normal option processing? Probably it's just `-v` that had to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/to/avidir; mkdir ../avidir2
pax -rwls '|.* - \(..\)x\(.. - \)|Series Title S\1 E\2|' *.avi ../avidir2
```

The above command will create hard-links to all of your files in another directory. This enables you to verify all of the changes are to your satisfaction before removing the files with the unwanted names.